# Content of the tab out of line

Tags: css, html

I do have html form, with a little structured design. I decided to add tabs and divide the content of file in to 2 parts. I used for this purpose jQuery, actually i just copied and paste code example from jQuery web site. It works, but the content of first tab is out of line. See below picture
[image]

I want it to fit in to the tab line. Here is the full code of this page, you maybe just will copy and see it on your side. I just left it in pastebin, dont want to spend time on formating it here:

[pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/kC1rEixA)

Comment: I dont quite understand your question. By tabs do you mean input fields? And how do you want what to fit in the tab line? You html is quite bad. For example id's need to be unique, you have a few hanging label tags and they shouldn't surround other tags such as divs, you shouldn't be using br tags for spacing, use css instead, etc..

Comment: validate your html and try again - http://validator.w3.org

Comment: @lukeocom, thanks for reply. I am absolutely beginner in html+css. If you can see at the picture the line titled as number 8 is out of line, i just wanted it to be inside the line. The problem is solved, i just extended the height of parentDiv. You mentioned about not using `br`, what should i use then? Thanks

Comment: for your divs you can apply margin or padding to add spacing. for example use in your style/css - div{margin:20px 10px;} this will set all your divs to have top and bottom spacing of 20px, and left and right spacing of 10px. You can also use margin-left, margin-top, etc..